# SDK 7.1 instllation for MATLAB

Tags: .net, matlab, visual-studio-2010

I have windows 8.1 64-bit OS. i want microsoft SDK 7.1 installed for my mex file compilation in MATLAB. To install SDK 7.1, i uninstalled

visual C++ 2010 redistributable (x64)
visual C++ 2010 redistributable (x86)

but still its traces are present in registry which stops SDK installation at vcredists_x64.exe. I tried to use microsoft fix-it to resolve my registry problem but fix-it doesn't run saying ".net framework 2 or greater required". while I already had .net framework 4.5.1 installed. I uninstalled .net framework to re-install it, but installer says that you already have 4.5.1 installed on your PC.
At present, I neither have

visual C++ 2010 redistributable (x64)
visual C++ 2010 redistributable (x86)

nor

microsoft .net framework 4.5.1

in my 'programs and features list'. but still problem in SDK 7.1 installation persists.

kindly help me getting SDK 7.1 installed for my MATLAB functionality

Comment: You should be able to install `.net2` on your machine even with `4.5` already installed, but you can also try to set the registry key: in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework`, create or modify `OnlyUseLatestCLR` to a `dword` with value `00000001`. This will force any program needing `.net` to use the latest one.

Comment: OnlyUseLatestCLR key is not available in my .net framework registry. I also downloaded .net framework 2.0. when i run the installer, nothing happens, not even a error.

Comment: i even created the OnlyUseLatestCLR DWORD in .net framework registry folder with value 00000001. but still no use